# Javascript/Jquery push json objects into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an json object coming from a `$.post` in jquery.
In order to loop through and store the data clientside I would like to add it to an array. For each search results that comes back I would like to "append" the array so it grows.

This is my json:

```
    {
"companies": [
{
  "companyid": "115",
  "saved": false,
  "orgnumber": "010101010",
  "companyname": "TestCompany",
  "header": "header info"
  },      
  {
  "companyid": "116",
  "saved": false,
  "orgnumber": "010101010",
  "companyname": "TestCompany",
  "header": "header info"
  } ]
      }
```

This is what I have come up with so far were data is the json 
comming back fron the post ajax request. Obj is just an object holding the array
which I declared further up in my code. obj.companies = new Array();

```
   obj.companies.push(data['companies']);
```

The next part I need to loop out the array. Trying to do it like this.

```
     $.each(obj.companies, function(i, item) {      

       // Does not alert correctly.
       alert(item.header);

     });
```

So I need to push the full json object into the array. But I cannot alert the item.header within the loop, how can I accomplish this?

EDIT:
Thanks everyone. Sorry if my question wasnt detailed enough.
I ended up doing this:

```
        getcompanies: function() {
          obj = this;
          $.post('api/finder/result.php', {}, function(data) {
                $.each(data.companies, function(i, item) {      
                    obj.companies.push(item);
                });             
                obj.loadcompanies();                        
          }, "json");
       },


        loadcompanies: function() {
           $.each(this.companies, function(i, item) {       
             alert(item.header);
          }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not terribly clear on what you want to do or why. Why are you stringifying the json before trying to add it to an object that appears to have a similar structure to the json you just stringified? What is the structure you're actually after?

Comment: What is actual question?

Comment: Also, demonstrated JSON is invalid.

Comment: As long as your `obj` has the array you're referring to (`{sresult: {companies: []}}`), what you're posting should loop over the data you've pushed, but the data you're pushing will be a `string` containing everything in the JSON.

Comment: Ofcourse something is wrong otherwise I would not ask the question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCool That's just it. You're NOT asking a question. You're posting background information, but no question that I can see. You're not saying what's not working, you're not saying what the current behaviour of your code is or what the expected behaviour is. We're basically just guessing at what could possibly be wrong because you're not telling us.

Comment: Ok so a loop is recommended? How do I get it to become an array like
obj.sresult['companies'] holding each array for each company? Also push new companies in the end of it.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will try to edit my question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCool I think you need to take a step back. I'm almost certain that whatever your problem is you're approaching it incorrectly. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: as @sigod points out, the data structure posted is invalid. You will get a better answer if you give us something more representative of what your json actually is

Comment: You can push json oject to array without stringifying it (it's should be valid js object...). Also you can youse javascript "filter" method to filter out specific objects from array by some of it's property values. This methos has it's implementations in all famous libraries, for example jQuery - $.grep

Comment: Im so sorry ya all. I have thought this through enough. My brain is fried after days of programming :D I'm now trying to push the data.companies directly into an obj.companies array instead. Hope it works. Perhaps this question can be removed.

Comment: @AdrianMcCool just delete the question yourself. Right now it has no future value to anyone

Comment: @AdrianMcCool That's OK. Just try to go through the "How do I ask a good question" section before posting a new one if you get stuck again. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, in case you will be struggling with populating subobjects (or getting data from them) do a research on recursive functions :)

Comment: Always prefer `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a issue with your server side code which is responsible for building JSON object which is getting returned via Ajax. The Correct JSON should be as follows:

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyid": "115",
            "saved": false,
            "orgnumber": "010101010",
            "companyname": "TestCompany",
            "header": "header info"
        },
        {
            "companyid": "116",
            "saved": false,
            "orgnumber": "010101010",
            "companyname": "TestCompany",
            "header": "header info"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that there is only single key with name "companies" which holds an array of objects. Please correct your server side code to get such valid JSON. You can use free online JSON validator tools such as http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON objects.

Now once you get such response from server; you just need to do following steps to get the companies array (following code will go into `$.post` success handler):

```
var jsonResp = JSON.parse(postResponse); //postResponse is the success resp of $.post
var companiesArray =  jsonResp.companies;
$.each(companiesArray , function (index, valueObj){
    var compId = valueObj.companyid;
    var isSaved = valueObj.saved;
});
```

I hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks! Great stuff, it helped, I finally did a loop and push it into the companies array.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append new company into your companies array you should

```
var json_obj =   {
"companies": [
{
  "companyid": "115",
  "saved": false,
  "orgnumber": "010101010",
  "companyname": "TestCompany",
  "header": "header info"
  },
  {
  "companyid": "116",
  "saved": false,
  "orgnumber": "010101010",
  "companyname": "TestCompany",
  "header": "header info"
  } ]
  };

  //adding new company into your companies array
  json_obj.companies.push({
     "companyid":"117",
     "saved" : false,
     "orgnumber": "20120313",
     "companyname":"anotherCompany",
     "header":"another header info"
  });

  //if you want to loop through your companies list you can:

  json_obj.companies.map(function ( obj ){
     console.log(obj.companyid);
     console.log(obj.companyname);
     etc..
  });
```

Comment: Yes correct, I posted badly formatted json. I noticed that I did not get the json as described in my question.